# Multiple webclients with different read/connection timeout configurations

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I want to have multiple webclients, each with different connection timeout configurations.

At the request level, API does not support connection timeout configuration.

I have a reusable library that configures webclient, and it so happens that since connection timeout is supported at config level , and not request level, the same config applies to all requests.

So i decided to go with one webclient per target service.

Can i pass parameters during bean initialisation with timeout durations specified?

Comment: You would need to create multiple `WebClient` instances with different configuration. If you are using beans - you need to create multiple beans for example using Spring `@Qualifier` annotation

Comment: I cannot use @Qualifier coz the webclient bean comes from a reusable/generic configurator

Comment: How do you plan to create a second client? Do you need bean?

Comment: well, i need to pass different readtimeout values from the properties file. Do i need a bean? i would prefer one, but not a strict requirement.

Comment: you need multiple `WebClient` instances. You can create some factory that takes `WebClient.Builder` as a param and construct `WebClient` for you with required timeout. If you want to use beans you would need to differentiate client somehow